# Raking to converting a convenience sample to representative sample

Tags: sampling, bias, resampling, representative

I have a convenience sample of patients in a [ZIP Code Tabulation Area](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/zctas.html) (ZCTA) for whom I know their gender and age. 
 I also have census data for the ZCTA (in particular I have 1) the percentage of males and females in the ZCTA, and 2) the percentage of the (estimated) population of the ZCTA that is made up of different age groups).

Would raking be the right approach to weight the convenience sample responses so that they constitutes a representative sample of the ZCTA with respect to the following measures:

1. The percentage of males and females in the sample, and
2. The percentage of each age group.

Comment: Rim aka raking weighting is applicable when the frequency distortions in cells are assumed to have been the result of independent marginal (main effect) distortions. For example, you have 2 gender by 3 age groups table. If it is reasonable to suppose that in your sample genders were disbalanced (comparitively with population) and ages were disbalanced - as two independent processes, then rim weighting, to restore the populational proportions, is the choice.

Comment: Can you describe an example of how gender and age could be disbalanced as dependent processes?

Comment: Any example where specific _cells_ are over- or underrepresented relative a population.

Comment: Can you define what a cell being over-represented means?  Suppose we say that the cell corresponding to Females in Age Group 20-29 is over-represented.  What would tell me that that cell is over-represented relative to the same cell for the population?

Comment: Let have variables sex (2 categories) and agegroup (3 categories). Let us know that proportions in all 6 cells are, say, equal in the population. Your representative data of, say, 150, should have 25 in each cell. But, unfortunately, you have underrepresented cell (1,3)=5 and overrepresented cell (2,2)=45. It is clear, that the weight correction should go between these two disbalanced cells only. Then all cell frequencies will be restored to be 25. However, if you apply classic _rim_weighting requesting marginal target proportions 1/2-1/2 and 1/3-1/3-1/3, you'll succeed in the (to cont.)

Comment: (cont.) marginal frequencies, but neither of cell frequencies will be 25. Which means you distorted the frequencies away from the population's. Because marginal rim procedure was inapplicable in the case where _specific cells_ in the table had undergo an under/over-representation. Rim assumes that the distorting "forces" were independent from the sides of gender and age.

Comment: Maybe I completely misunderstand raking, but isn't raking to be used exactly when the sample cell counts **do not** match the population cell counts?  If the sample cell counts matched the population cell counts there would be no reason to use raking, right?

Comment: The key is (the assumption) _how_ the cell proportions got distorted comapratively the population (the wanted) proportions). On my web page, there is macro "weighting groups"; you might want ot read its description document, to understand what I mean by the "assumption rim weighting is making".